# Get two devices to communicate over WiFi without going through IP (p2p over the WiFi layers only)

Tags: c#, wifi, p2p

I need to get two machines to communicate via WiFi without using IP (I do not want to use IP sockets). The solution preferably should work with both WiFi modes (infrastructure such as regular WiFi and ad-hoc such as WiFi Direct). A C# sample code would be great please.

I have searched a lot and could not find any code similar to a socket program that sends and receives data between two machines (p2p) but using only WiFi without any IP.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to avoid IP?  To bypass IP you would basically have to talk to the WiFi device driver, which the OS may not let you do, and would likely change for different devices.  To me it seems like UDP (which uses IP) would accomplish much the same results with less effort.

Comment: This question has several problems: Sockets are an abstraction provided by the operating system on top of TCP, which uses IP to deliver data reliably. Wi-Fi Direct does not operate in 802.11 'ad-hoc' mode, it uses hidden infrastructure networks.

Comment: First of all thank you for your comments. However my question is not answered and maybe not very clear: is there a way to get two machines to communicate via WiFi without using any layers beyond layer 2 in the OSI model? If so is there a C# code sample for that?
I was hoping that there would be an API in the .NET similar to for example Serial communication API where a machine could listen to, receive, and send data via WiFi without any need for TCP/IP. The communication would use WiFi mac addresses to locate machines and not IP addresses.

Comment: @samman what you want to do is certainly possible, but it requires using very low level facilities (c, driver APIs, etc.), which is at odds with your desire to do all this in a very high level language (C#).

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Multi-Peer Connectivity framework supports setting up a Peer to Peer connection without the developer having to manage the IP connectivity directly, but it uses IP to deliver data and is limited to Apple devices.

It's possible to do this if you are willing to write the low-level c code to do it, but any solution which avoids IP will have to recreate significant portions of the protocol to be useful and would almost certainly require much more work than just using the IP features of the OS.

For very simple forms of communication between Wi-Fi stations you can use custom Action Frames and Information Elements, but those require very low-level access to the driver.

Comment: Any docs to read on Action Forms and Information Elements? Any examples in C# for low-level access to the drivers?

Comment: @samman for the Action Frames and Information Elements you can refer to the IEEE 802.11 family of specifications: http://standards.ieee.org/about/get/802/802.11.html

Comment: For bridging of C# code have a look at the Platform Invoke tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx